# "Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor" error for no reason?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Return Latency",
  execute(message, args, client, Discord) {
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle(' Pong!')
      .setDescription(`Latency is **${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms**. API Latency is **${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms**`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('Some footer text here", "https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
    message.channel.send(newEmbed);
  }
}
```

When I try to call the `ping` command, I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor
at Object.execute (/app/commands/ping.js:5:22)
at module.exports (/app/events/guild/message.js:42:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/c4865ae1-ea5f-4cc0-b0f4-0eba4d95ab89/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

I'm using discord.js version 12.5.1 and node.js version 14.15.2. I don't understand why I'm even receiving this error.

A portion of my `message.js` code:

```js
try{
    command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord);
} catch (err){
    message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord)` but your function is `execute(message, args, client, Discord)`. This way, when you try to use `Discord.MessageEmbed` in your function, you actually call `client.MessageEmbed`.

Check the difference between the number of arguments/parameters. You will either need to use:

```js
command.execute(message, args, client, Discord);
```

Or...

```js
execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) { ...
```